# Legendre polynomials in python

Tags: python, polynomials, polynomial-math, polynomial-approximations

How to generate ORTHONORMAL basis of Legendre polynomials on [0,1]?

I tried using many modules, but they usually don’t provide normalisation and change of interval. Is there some general normalizing factor? Or formula for change of the interval?

Comment: Are you trying to get a python function ? Or can this be stored in any data layout ?
Anyway, I recommend learning [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) for all math stuff. They do have legendre stuff [See their documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html#sympy.functions.special.polynomials.legendre).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Legendre polynomials on `[-1, 1]` with `scipy.special.legendre`. They are orthogonal but not orthonormal. But [it is known](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html) that the integral of `Ln(x)*Ln(x)` over `[-1, 1]` is `2 / (2*n +1)`, where `Ln` denotes the Legendre polynomial of degree `n`. So you can normalize the Legendre polynomials as follows:

```py
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.special import legendre
from math import sqrt

l3 = legendre(3, monic=False)

integrate.quad(lambda x: l3(x)*l3(x), -1, 1) # = 2 / (2*degree + 1)

def l3normalized(x):
    return sqrt((2*3 + 1) / 2) * l3(x)

integrate.quad(lambda x: l3normalized(x)*l3normalized(x), -1, 1) # = 1
```

Now, to change the interval, you can do a linear change of variables: define `Pn` on `[0, 1]` by `Pn(x) = sqrt(2) * Ln_normalized(2*x-1)`. Then the `Pn` are orthonormal.

```py
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.special import legendre
from math import sqrt

l3 = legendre(3, monic=False)

integrate.quad(lambda x: l3(x)*l3(x), -1, 1) # = 2 / (2*degree + 1)

def l3normalized(x):
    return sqrt((2*3 + 1) / 2) * l3(x)

integrate.quad(lambda x: l3normalized(x)*l3normalized(x), -1, 1) # = 1

l4 = legendre(4, monic=False)
def l4normalized(x):
    return sqrt((2*4 + 1) / 2) * l4(x)

def p3(x):
    return sqrt(2) * l3normalized(2*x-1)

def p4(x):
    return sqrt(2) * l4normalized(2*x-1)

integrate.quad(lambda x: p3(x)*p3(x), 0, 1) # = 1
integrate.quad(lambda x: p3(x)*p4(x), 0, 1) # = 0
```